# How can I rename an external drive?

Tags: disk

I would like to rename an external drive (USB).

How can I rename an external drive?

Answer (score 3):

Among many other options, you can start application *Disk Utility* and select the disk/device to rename. <kbd>*Unmount*</kbd> the partition if needed. You can then find an option for assigning new label to the disk - the <kbd>Edit a Filesystem Label</kbd>, click that to rename the device.

[image: snap1]

[image: snap2]

Comment: No need to unmount the partition for changing labels.

Comment: @Takkat, for FAT, NTFS filesystems I have to.. and yes for ext* you don't have to..