# How can I rename an external HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, drive

I have an external drive whose name used to be "2nd Brain". I lent it to a friend who renamed it but now I can't manage to rename it again. I followed the instructions from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410408/how-can-i-rename-an-external-drive), to use the disk utility to change the name, but as soon as I enter `2nd Brain` it automatically becomes `2ND BRAIN`.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The filesystem format was FAT32, but now its listed as msdos. My friend must have changed that too. How do I change it back and how can I change the drive's name without having it capitalized?

Comment: What advice? What topic? You might want to take the [tour] or visit the [help] to familiarize yourself with how this site works. We're not a forum. If you are referring to another Q&A on this site, please [edit] your question and include a link to it. Also, [edit] your question and explain exactly what steps you took or what commands you ran.

Comment: Also please include what filesystem the drive is formatted as.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/276911/how-to-rename-partitions)

Comment: Yes, as I indicated above. But the answer given resulted in another issue. Hence my question. What are the other methods referred to in that answer?

Comment: @terdon did I satisfy your requirements with my edits?

Comment: Yes, thanks. That link was helpful. Note, however, that these aren't "my" requirements. I'm just trying to help you get an answer.

Comment: I suspect `msdos` is the partition table type, rather than the filesystem type. According to this [su] comment, the FAT32 standard supports lower case / mixed case although some Linux tools follow the Windows practice of not supporting it [Setting a mixed-case volume label for a FAT32 drive on Windows](http://superuser.com/q/137569/549309) - the comment suggests trying `fatlabel` from the dosfstools package.

Comment: @steeldriver dosfstools package? I'm not that knowledgeable with computers. Can you walk me through it?

Comment: @TonySeverino - The generic usage is `sudo fatlabel /dev/sdxN my_label` , where "x" is the drive letter, "N" is the partition (most likely 1) and "my_label" is self-explanatory.

Comment: Correction... It said: sudo: fatlabel: command not found

Comment: Did you install the `dosfstools` package?

Comment: OK, I had my system checked out by a member of the public library IT staff. He said steeldriver was right, its because of a partition table.

Comment: @steeldriver, I already have it. How do I run it?